# Refresh a specific external data connection

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file (2007) that has 50+ connections and takes about 5 minutes to refresh all.

The workbook is refreshed daily by the users. Not all connections are ready to be refreshed in the morning. Some are ready and some are not, depending on the server status.

I created a table that shows an estimated time to refresh (let's call it ETR table), which takes a second to refresh. I want the users to refresh only this ETR table while there is still pending work in the server. Once they have green lights on all the connections in ETR table, they can refresh all.

The problem is that the main sheet to which the users have access is protected and cannot have any external connections (otherwise, the table won't refresh). Therefore, I placed the ETR table in a hidden but unprotected sheet and show the values in the main sheet using formulas. Since they cannot access ETR table directly, there's no good way for the users to refresh only the ETR table.

Therefore, I'd like to make a command button (or anything that'd work) where the users can click and refresh just one specific table.

I am very new to VBA, and have been researching it for days but I could only find codes to refresh Pivot tables, not external data connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this:

`ThisWorkbook.Connections("server.amer.company.com_tabular Tabular Model").Refresh`

With your connection name in place of the string.

If you need to find what each connection is called you could loop through like this:

```
Sub loop_connections()
    i = 1
    For Each wb_connection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        Debug.Print wb_connection
        Sheet1.Cells(i,1).Value = wb_connection
        i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Alternatively, if as part of your connection you have a table in your workbook you can refresh that like this:

`Sheet1.ListObjects("Table_Name").TableObject.Refresh`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

i think you could use

`Thisworkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").Refresh`

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well! Have a nice day.